# Pass props to function that is spread within an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, emotion

Working in React, I need to pass props from the instanced component into the `mockFn` here. This is an extracted example but it's using Material UI, and im just stuck a bit on the concept / how to structure it so I have access to `props`.

In the example below, the `background` part allows me to access props with the arrow function, but for the `mockFn` bit where i need to spread the result inline, i cannot pass props to it.

I thought i could do props => ...mockFn() but that doesn't work.

```js
const mockFn = props => ({
  color: props.color,
  //...
});

const StyledSelect = withStyles(
  {
    root: {
      // works fine
      background: props => props.bgColor,

      // how to pass props to this mockFn?
      ...mockFn()

     // does not work
    props => ...mockFn(props)
    }
  },
  {}
)(Select);

<StyledSelect bgColor="green" color="red" />
```

Full example on https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-res5e?file=/demo.js:586-767

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea about material-ui but i know in styled components this works:

```js
...(props) => mockFn(props)
```

have a go at it and tell me what happened

Answer (score 0):

You can get the props at the rule level (e.g. `root`) rather than for the individual CSS properties.

Here is the syntax you want:

```
const StyledSelect = withStyles({
  root: (props) => ({
    background: props.bgColor,
    ...mockFn(props)
  })
})(Select);
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]